# Eclipse Web Developement - Manually defining server

Tags: eclipse

I've been working mostly with Java for a while but now I'm about to head in to web developing for the first time. I intend to do this in Eclipse and I've installed the plugins. Creating the Web project and HTML file works just fine but when I try to run the application and try to manually define a new server, only J2EE appears under Basic.

This is what its looks like:
[image: Select the server type]

I've been following this tutorial which works up until 5:30 when he gets different options than me.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URCyWNflkpQ

This is what I've got installed:
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools,
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools,
Eclipse Web Developer Tools,
JST Server Adapter,
JST Server Adapter Extension

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking that link "Download additional server adapters".

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
What do I pick there?
Theres about 20 extensions to choose from.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0mkitdxildn986/Screenshot%202015-02-24%2010.46.59.png?dl=0

Comment: That's really a personal choice, you should use whatever J2EE container you're comfortable or familiar with. I go with Tomcat myself because I have lots of experience with it even though it's probably not the best choice in 2015.

Comment: Here's a tutorial for Tomcat with Eclipse, don't know how up to date it is though.

http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html